# Передача изменяемого параметра в класс Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

У меня есть страница с полями для ввода PageCreate. Некоторые из этих полей должны выбираться из справочников. Для справочников реализован отдельный класс `SearchHelp`, который отрисовывает поле для его выбора. В этом поле есть стрелка, по которой открывается новая страница (новый класс `ListItemSearchHelp`) с вариантами выбора. После того как был выбран нужный вариант, он возвращается в класс `SearchHelp` с помощью функции:

```dart
void _returnDataFromSecondScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) =>
            BlocProvider.value(
              value: BlocProvider.of<ReferencesCubit>(
                  context),
              child: ListItemSearchHelp(
                  widget.name, widget.nameReference),
            ));
    final result = await Navigator.push(context, route);

    setState(() {
      txt.text = result;
    });
  }

txt = TextEditingController();
```

txt - контроллер для поля ввода значения справочника
На странице `PageCreate` это поле вызывается так:
`SearchHelp` (заголовок, имя таблицы локальной бд в которой лежат данные справочника)
Как вернуть значение, полученное в результате выбора значения справочника в контроллере `txt.text` (в классе `SearchHelp`) на страницу с полями для ввода `PageCreate`?